# app Android con Oauth Foursquare

Tags: android, oauth

Estoy desarrollando una app en Android Studio (Kotlin) que utiliza Oauth con Forsquare y utilizo la siguiente variable

```
val codigoRespuesta = FoursquareOAuth.getAuthCodeFromResult(resultCode, data)
```

Al ejecutar....

```
codigoRespuesta = com.foursquare.android.nativeoauth.model.AuthCodeResponse@7cd1d03
```

Luego guardo el código en otra variable

```
val codigo = codigoRespuesta.code
```

, pero en esta instrucción mi variable codigo queda nula.

En el momento de la ejecución de la app aparece esta ventana
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar? Que debo hacer para que la variable codigo no quede nula?

Comment: El problema es en la petición, identifica el error como comento en mi respuesta y agrégalo en tu pregunta o realiza una nueva pregunta con esta información, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes un código con valor null en este punto:

```
val codigo = codigoRespuesta.code
```

**esto es debido seguramente a que se obtuvo un error, debes validar si obtienes un error, (y obviamente corregirlo) en la petición**.

Este es un ejemplo basado en tu código de lo que debe realizarse, al identificar  el error es más fácil realizar la corrección :

```
  val codigoRespuesta = FoursquareOAuth.getAuthCodeFromResult(resultCode, data)
  //Obtiene error
  val exception = codigoRespuesta.exception
  //Realiza logica despues de evaluar respuesta.

       if (exception == null) { // Success.
            val code = codigoRespuesta.code
            //Al no obtener error realiza el intercambio del token.
            //performTokenExchange(code)
        } else {
            if (exception is FoursquareCancelException) { // Cancel.
                toastMessage(this, "Canceled")
            } else if (exception is FoursquareDenyException) { // Deny.
                toastMessage(this, "Denied")
            } else if (exception is FoursquareOAuthException) { // OAuth error.
                val errorMessage = exception.message
                val errorCode = exception.errorCode
                toastMessage(this, "$errorMessage [$errorCode]")
            } else if (exception is FoursquareUnsupportedVersionException) { // Unsupported Fourquare app version on the device.
                toastError(this, exception)
            } else if (exception is FoursquareInvalidRequestException) { // Invalid request.
                toastError(this, exception)
            } else { // Error.
                toastError(this, exception)
            }
        }
```

Es importante revises este ejemplo de la implementación:

[Foursquare Android OAuth](https://github.com/foursquare/foursquare-android-oauth/tree/master/foursquare-oauth-sample)

Comment: Hola, en el exception que capturo el valor es nulo, ósea que no hay mensaje de error. Lo que hice para solucionar el inconveniente fue desinstalar la app de Foursquare de mi celular. Gracias